# GAE dev_appserver.py over HTTPS

Tags: google-app-engine, https

Has anyone cracked how to get HTTPS working on the dev_appserver.py? I need it for Facebook canvas app testing. I've had a search of the docs and nothing suggests there's a way to do it (sticking 'secure' in the app.yaml doesn't nothing locally).

I was think there may be a way to proxy it, but has anyone got any experience of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dev_appserver doesn't support HTTPS. The only practical way to do this is to set up a reverse proxy in front of your app - such as with nginx or Apache - and have it proxy SSL traffic to your app.

Comment: @AhmedNuaman That would be a different question - and one for serverfault.com, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

**I know this is late**, in case anybody else finds this question:

[ngrok](http://ngrok.com) is quiet easy to setup for a custom reverse HTTPS proxy..

The only downside is that my webapp2 application still believes it's being served over HTTP, so using `redirect()` doesn't work well because it resolves relative URLs to absolute URLs using `request.url`.

My workaround was to overwrite `RequestHandler.redirect` as follows:

```
class BaseRequestHandler(RequestHandler):
  def redirect(self, uri, permanent = False, abort = False, code = None, body = None):
    if uri.startswith(('.', '/')):
      base_url = self.request.url
      if base_url.startswith('http://'):
        base_url = 'https://' + base_url[7:]
      uri = str(urlparse.urljoin(base_url, uri))
    super(RequestHandler, self).redirect(uri, permanent, abort, code, body)
```

I needed a `BaseRequestHandler` class anyways for implementing other utility functions.

Answer (score 0):

I put this in my Appache httpd.conf to proxy the connection:

```
<Location /myproject/>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
</Location>
```

Now going to `https://localhost/myproject/` in my browser worked.

Note: SSL needs to be enabled on your Apache server. On my OS X machine I uncommented out the line `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and ran sudo apachectl restart