# Simple HTTPS to HTTP proxy

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, fido-u2f

I'm trying to test out [U2F](https://developers.yubico.com/U2F/) on Google Appengine.

Unfortunately `dev_appserver.py`, the development app server for local testing, only [runs in HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849020), and the U2F standard requires that the web server be connected over HTTPS.

There are some options for proxy servers, including [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html), [stud](https://github.com/bumptech/stud), [Pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound) and [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

What I am doing will probably end up being an open source package, so I would like to keep the setup fairly straightforward and dependency list strictly to widely available packages.

An ideal solution would be a command-line program along the lines of `prog_name -listen localhost:8041 -proxy localhost:8040`; in other words, a very simple command line setup.

The `stud` and `pound` programs seem like overkill.

The `stunnel` option seems to be the best and most common solution, but it would be better if it could be configured from the command line instead of a config file.

Ngrok is super-cool and seems to be along the right lines. It gives you a random server name though, which can be a problem since the U2F `appId` must match the server (if persistence matters), but other than that it's basically the right idea.

I have a vague memory of this being possible with `openssl` from the command line, but the only command that seems suitable is `s_server` and that seems to only provide ssl reflection/debugging information and not the option to proxy requests per se.  My memory must be faulty.

It would not be terribly difficult to write-up a trivial Python server/client proxy, leading me to believe there's probably a simple option out there ... however, the search results have a dreadful signal-noise ratio.

Are there other sensible options for developing with a HTTPS server when the content is served over HTTP (as the case is with AppEngine's `dev_appserver.py`)?

Comment: Some other options here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7585056