# Connect GAE Remote API to dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to execute a Python script that connects to my local dev_appserver.py instance to run some DataStore queries.

The dev_appserver.py is running with:

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

As per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi I have:

```
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth(
    hostname,
    '/_ah/remote_api'
)
```

In the Python script, but what should the hostname be set to?

For example, when dev_appserver.py started, it prints:

```
INFO     2016-10-18 12:02:16,850 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:56700
```

But I set the value to localhost:56700, I get the following error:

```
httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

(Same error for any port that has anything running on it - e.g. 8000, 8080, etc).

If anyone has managed to get this to run successfully, what hostname did you use?

Many thanks,
Ned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dev_appserver.py` doesn't support SSL (I can't find the doc reference anymore), so it can't answer `https://` requests.

You could try using http-only URLs (not sure if possible with the remote API - I didn't use it yet, may need to disable handler `secure` option in `app.yaml` config files).

At least on my devserver I am able to direct my browser to the http-only API server URL reported by `devserver.py` at startup and I see `{app_id: dev~my_app_name, rtok: '0'}`.

Or you could setup a proxy server, see [GAE dev_appserver.py over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849020/gae-dev-appserver-py-over-https).

Comment: You were 99% there and gave me what I needed to figure out the final 1%, so I'll mark as Answer. For anyone reading this - the answer is to use the "API Server" host (so localhost:56700 for above) and then add "secure=False" to the remote_api_stub call.

    remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth(
        'localhost:56700',
        '/_ah/remote_api',
        secure=False
    )