# Does Google App Engine Node.js local dev server support SSL?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

To test my nodejs Google App Engine app locally, I run a local node instance per the github examples and [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app).  But node does not support HTTPS without setting up the https module and installing a certificate.  Does the Google Cloud SDK not already support SSL connections for local dev servers?  I am surprised I am not seeing that feature.  Initially I will need it to test Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL support depends on the local server capability, not on the SDK itself.

The development server bundled with the SDK (only used for standard environment apps!) doesn't support SSL at all: [GAE dev_appserver.py over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849020/gae-dev-appserver-py-over-https)

For your flexible environment app the local server is your node server. So you could set that up for HTTPS. Or you could evaluate the proxy approach, an example is documented here: [Appengine - Local dev server with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867175/appengine-local-dev-server-with-https)