# Google Cloud App Engine: How to serve https in a Flexible environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I work on a python3.6 app that uses flask and oauth2client.

I want to serve https instead of http in gcloud environment.

I tried using talisman-flask:

> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman

However, when I ran their sample app locally I got this error in my browser:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
>   127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.

It works fine for http, but can't apparently serve https.

Are there some Talisman configurations I need to change?
Or maybe a whole different solution altogheter?

**EDIT:**

I changed from `debug=True` to `debug=False` and now I get automatically redirected to https but the above error message is still there.

Answer (score 0):

One rather generic approach which can work even with the standard environment local development server (which doesn't support HTTPS) would be to use a reverse proxy.

Such solutions are documented in [Appengine - Local dev server with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867175/appengine-local-dev-server-with-https/)

Answer (score 0):

It's an old thread, but if you want to serve HTTPS (with or without Talisman) you need, at least, a valid certificate. Please, create one at Let's Encrypt and install in your web server, even if your site are in the [web](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) or in your [local](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/) environment. If you want a good tutorial to help further, I recommend [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https) from Miguel Grinberg, a big "Flask Guru" ;-) .